# Filtering documents by number of nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a index full of documents with the following structure:

```
{
  name: "The sound and the fury",
  tags: [{ name: "confusing", id: "uuid1"}, {name: "sad", id: "uuid-2"}]
}
```

I'd like to get all documents that have more than two tags.

I've tried something like the following:

```
{
 "query": {
 "bool": {
   "must": [
     {
      "script": {
        "script": "doc['tags'].value.size() == 1"
      }
     }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

But I get a script error: `No field found for [tags] in mapping with types`. I receive the same error with a script of `"doc['tags'].size() == 1"`

I'm running elasticsearch 5.6; performance is not an issue since I am using this for debugging and testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the index mapping to enable fielddata. here is a sample mapping.

```
   put your_index_name/_mapping/doc
    {
       "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "tags": {
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "text",
                "fielddata":true,
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "text","fielddata":true,
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
}
```

and use the following query

```
get your_index_name/_search
{ 
"query": {
 "bool": {
   "must": [
     {
      "script": {
        "script": "doc['tags.value'].length > 2"
      }
     }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: My original example did not include the actual nested documents. I've updated the question body to match the title which should hopefully make things clearer. Apologies for the bait and switch!

Comment: ok. edited with nested source. updated the mapping and query.

Answer (score 2):

as mentioned by Pari Rajaram, you'll need to update the mapping.
However, I'd take a different approach, that is, mapping the `tags.id` to a keyword type (IMHO, a better datatype for an id).

This way, your query will look like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc['tags.id'].size() == 1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```